# ReactJS - pass parameter to fetch request

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router, mern

Following is the React component displaying all categories,
at this route http://localhost:3000/categories

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";
import { Link } from "react-router-dom";
// Material-UI core
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';
import Container from '@material-ui/core/Container';
// Local Components
import BodyWrapper from 'components/bodyWrapper';
import Spinner from 'components/progressAnimations/spinner';
import CategoryCard from 'components/categoryCard';

import { CARD1, CARD2, CARD3 } from '../../constants'; // images
import { useStyles } from './style';

function Categories(props) {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const loading = useSelector(state => state.categories.isLoading);
    const categories = useSelector(state => state.categories.categories);

    return (
        <BodyWrapper spacing = "40px" containerWidth = "lg">
            <h2>Categories</h2>
            <Grid container spacing={4}>
                {
                    !loading ?
                    categories.data[0].documents.map((category, index) => (
                        <Grid key={index} item xs={6} md={4} lg={3} >
                            <Link to = {`/categories/${category.name}`} style={{ textDecoration: "none" }}>
                            <CategoryCard image={ category.imageUrl || CARD2 } title={ category.name } />
                            </Link>
                        </Grid>
                    )) : (
                        <div className = { classes.spinner }>
                            <Spinner />
                        </div>
                    )
                }
            </Grid>
        </BodyWrapper>
    );
}

export default Categories;
```

When clicked on a specific category I want load a new component and create a GET request to server with the id of category to load all data related to category.

http://localhost:3000/categories/Photographers

This is the API URL, I want to send "categories id" with the GET request.

```
{{SERVER}}/api/vendor/getAll?page=1&limit=10&categories=5fdf4d9db1ecf930cd09331b
```

I want know the best way to pass categories id to next component.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it like this:

```
import React, { useEffect, useState } from "react";
import axios from "axios";

const Categories = (props) => {
  // we get something from Redux
  const categories = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"];
  const [currentCategory, setCurrentCategory] = useState(null);

  return props.loading ? (
    "Loading..."
  ) : (
    <div>
      <h2>Select category</h2>
      {categories.map((category) => (
        <div key={category} onClick={() => setCurrentCategory(category)}>
          Category: {category}
        </div>
      ))}
      <div>current category is {String(currentCategory)}</div>
      {currentCategory && <Category id={currentCategory} />}
    </div>
  );
};

const Category = ({ id }) => {
  const [data, setData] = useState(null);

  const url = "https://someurl.com";

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchData = async () => {
      const dataFromServer = await axios.get(`${url}/${id}`);
      setData(dataFromServer);
    };
    fetchData();
  }, [id]);

  return data ? (
    <div>Render data here: {data}</div>
  ) : (
    `Loading category ${id}...`
  );
};

const App = () => {
  return (
    <div>
      <Categories />
    </div>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: Hello @Konstantin thanks for your solution. But have I URL like this:
localhost:3000/categories/Food
I don't want to pass id in URL.

When app loads an API request is made using Redux thunk  to get all categories and saved in store. 

One solution I have in mind is to use Redux's store, Search with category name from URL param of Route and pick corresponding id.
But I am not sure if this is a good approach

Comment: in your question you wrote: "When clicked on a specific category I want load a new component and create a GET request to server with the id of category to load all data related to category."  Now you want to get all data initially, and then show selected Category? wiith data from state ? Do you need routing for that category ?

Comment: I am not loading all data initially, Just the list of categories when app loads. Then if clicked on a category I want to use the id of that category to load data for a particular category e.g. List of Photographers, Decorators etc.